# MeshCollider copy slow for physics

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a tiled world, where tiles are made of GameObjects. However, I would like to have physics in this GameObject. If I instantiate a GameObject for each tile, I get framedrops, and if I use a reference the physics are the same for each tile (i.e. a ball drops on one tile, walk a little further and it has already dropped on the next).

Is there a solution for the above problem?

Edit: See the last part where I made some additions.

Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/// <summary>
/// A double key dictionary.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="K">
/// The first key type.
/// </typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="T">
/// The second key type.
/// </typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="V">
/// The value type.
/// </typeparam>
/// <remarks>
/// See http://noocyte.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/double-key-dictionary/
///   A Remove method was added.
/// </remarks>
public class DoubleKeyDictionary<K, T, V> : IEnumerable<DoubleKeyPairValue<K, T, V>>, 
                                            IEquatable<DoubleKeyDictionary<K, T, V>>
{
    #region Constants and Fields

    /// <summary>
    /// The m_inner dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    private Dictionary<T, V> m_innerDictionary;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors and Destructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DoubleKeyDictionary{K,T,V}"/> class. 
    ///   Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DoubleKeyDictionary&lt;K, T, V&gt;"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public DoubleKeyDictionary()
    {
        this.OuterDictionary = new Dictionary<K, Dictionary<T, V>>();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets OuterDictionary.
    /// </summary>
    private Dictionary<K, Dictionary<T, V>> OuterDictionary { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Public Indexers

    /// <summary>
    ///   Gets or sets the value with the specified indices.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value></value>
    public V this[K index1, T index2]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.OuterDictionary[index1][index2];
        }

        set
        {
            this.Add(index1, index2, value);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears this dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    public void Clear()
    {
        OuterDictionary.Clear();
        if (m_innerDictionary!=null)
            m_innerDictionary.Clear();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key1">
    /// The key1.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="key2">
    /// The key2.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="value">
    /// The value.
    /// </param>
    public void Add(K key1, T key2, V value)
    {
        if (this.OuterDictionary.ContainsKey(key1))
        {
            if (this.m_innerDictionary.ContainsKey(key2))
            {
                this.OuterDictionary[key1][key2] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                this.m_innerDictionary = this.OuterDictionary[key1];
                this.m_innerDictionary.Add(key2, value);
                this.OuterDictionary[key1] = this.m_innerDictionary;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.m_innerDictionary = new Dictionary<T, V>();
            this.m_innerDictionary[key2] = value;
            this.OuterDictionary.Add(key1, this.m_innerDictionary);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the specified dictionary contains the key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index1">
    /// The index1.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="index2">
    /// The index2.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// <c>true</c> if the specified index1 contains key; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </returns>
    public bool ContainsKey(K index1, T index2)
    {
        if (!this.OuterDictionary.ContainsKey(index1))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!this.OuterDictionary[index1].ContainsKey(index2))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Equalses the specified other.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">
    /// The other.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The equals.
    /// </returns>
    public bool Equals(DoubleKeyDictionary<K, T, V> other)
    {
        if (this.OuterDictionary.Keys.Count != other.OuterDictionary.Keys.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }

        bool isEqual = true;

        foreach (var innerItems in this.OuterDictionary)
        {
            if (!other.OuterDictionary.ContainsKey(innerItems.Key))
            {
                isEqual = false;
            }

            if (!isEqual)
            {
                break;
            }

            // here we can be sure that the key is in both lists, 
            // but we need to check the contents of the inner dictionary
            Dictionary<T, V> otherInnerDictionary = other.OuterDictionary[innerItems.Key];
            foreach (var innerValue in innerItems.Value)
            {
                if (!otherInnerDictionary.ContainsValue(innerValue.Value))
                {
                    isEqual = false;
                }

                if (!otherInnerDictionary.ContainsKey(innerValue.Key))
                {
                    isEqual = false;
                }
            }

            if (!isEqual)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return isEqual;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the enumerator.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// </returns>
    public IEnumerator<DoubleKeyPairValue<K, T, V>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var outer in this.OuterDictionary)
        {
            foreach (var inner in outer.Value)
            {
                yield return new DoubleKeyPairValue<K, T, V>(outer.Key, inner.Key, inner.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the specified key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key1">
    /// The key1.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="key2">
    /// The key2.
    /// </param>
    public void Remove(K key1, T key2)
    {
        this.OuterDictionary[key1].Remove(key2);
        if (this.OuterDictionary[key1].Count == 0)
        {
            this.OuterDictionary.Remove(key1);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Explicit Interface Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through a collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An <see cref="T:System.Collections.IEnumerator"/> object that can be used to iterate through the collection.
    /// </returns>
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
/// Represents two keys and a value.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="K">
/// First key type.
/// </typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="T">
/// Second key type.
/// </typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="V">
/// Value type.
/// </typeparam>
public class DoubleKeyPairValue<K, T, V>
{
    #region Constructors and Destructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DoubleKeyPairValue{K,T,V}"/> class. 
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DoubleKeyPairValue&lt;K, T, V&gt;"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key1">
    /// The key1.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="key2">
    /// The key2.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="value">
    /// The value.
    /// </param>
    public DoubleKeyPairValue(K key1, T key2, V value)
    {
        this.Key1 = key1;
        this.Key2 = key2;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    /// <summary>
    ///   Gets or sets the key1.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The key1.</value>
    public K Key1 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Gets or sets the key2.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The key2.</value>
    public T Key2 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Gets or sets the value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The value.</value>
    public V Value { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a <see cref="System.String"/> that represents this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="System.String"/> that represents this instance.
    /// </returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Key1 + " - " + this.Key2 + " - " + this.Value;
    }

    #endregion
}

public class TerrainManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject playerGameObject;
    public GameObject referenceTerrain;
    public int spread = 1;
    public int rememberSpread = 3;

    private int[] currentTerrainID;
    private DoubleKeyDictionary<int, int, GameObject> terrainUsageData;
    private Vector3 referencePosition;
    private Vector2 referenceSize;
    private Quaternion referenceRotation;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        currentTerrainID = new int[2];
        terrainUsageData = new DoubleKeyDictionary<int, int, GameObject>();

        referencePosition = referenceTerrain.transform.position;
        referenceRotation = referenceTerrain.transform.rotation;

        float width = 0;
        float height = 0;
        foreach(Renderer rend in referenceTerrain.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>()) {
            if (rend.bounds.size.x > width)
                width = rend.bounds.size.x;
            if (rend.bounds.size.z > height)
                height = rend.bounds.size.z;
        }

        referenceSize = new Vector2(width, height);
        print (referenceSize);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Vector3 warpPosition = playerGameObject.transform.position;
        TerrainIDFromPosition(ref currentTerrainID, ref warpPosition);

        string dbgString = "";
        dbgString = "CurrentID : " + currentTerrainID[0] + ", " + currentTerrainID[1] + "\n\n";
        for(int i=-spread;i<=spread;i++)
        {
            for(int j=-spread;j<=spread;j++)
            {   
                DropTerrainAt(currentTerrainID[0] + i, currentTerrainID[1] + j);
                dbgString += (currentTerrainID[0] + i) + "," + (currentTerrainID[1] + j) + "\n";
            }
        }
        Debug.Log(dbgString);
        ReclaimTiles();
    }

    void TerrainIDFromPosition(ref int[] currentTerrainID, ref Vector3 position)
    {
        currentTerrainID[0] = Mathf.RoundToInt((position.x - referencePosition.x) / referenceSize.x);
        currentTerrainID[1] = Mathf.RoundToInt((position.z - referencePosition.z) / referenceSize.y);
    }

    void DropTerrainAt(int i, int j)
    {
        if(terrainUsageData.ContainsKey(i,j))
        {
            // Restore the data for this tile
        }
        else
        {
            // Create a new data object
            terrainUsageData[i,j] = CreateNewTerrainData();
        }

        ActivateUsedTile(i, j);
    }

    GameObject CreateNewTerrainData()
    {
        GameObject terr = (GameObject)Instantiate(referenceTerrain);
        terr.SetActive(true);
        return terr;
    }

    void ReclaimTiles()
    {
        foreach(DoubleKeyPairValue<int,int,GameObject> pair in terrainUsageData)
        {
            if (pair.Key1 > currentTerrainID[0] + rememberSpread || pair.Key1 < currentTerrainID[0] - rememberSpread ||
                    pair.Key2 > currentTerrainID[1] + rememberSpread || pair.Key2 < currentTerrainID[1] - rememberSpread) {
                pair.Value.SetActive(false);
                terrainUsageData.Remove(pair.Key1, pair.Key2);
            }
        }
    }

    void ActivateUsedTile(int i, int j)
    {
        terrainUsageData[i,j].transform.position = 
                                    new Vector3(    referencePosition.x + i * referenceSize.x,
                                                    referencePosition.y,
                                                    referencePosition.z + j * referenceSize.y);
        terrainUsageData[i,j].transform.rotation = referenceRotation;
        terrainUsageData[i,j].SetActive(true);
            foreach(Transform ct in terrainUsageData[i,j].transform) {
                if (!ct.gameObject.name.Equals("Ground"))
                    ct.gameObject.rigidbody.isKinematic = false;
            }
    }   
}
```

And my additional changes:

```
        GameObject terr = new GameObject();
        foreach(Transform go in referenceTerrain.transform) {
            GameObject obj = new GameObject();

            GameObject origobj = go.gameObject;

            obj.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
            MeshRenderer mr = obj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
            mr.materials = origobj.renderer.materials;
            mr.receiveShadows = origobj.renderer.receiveShadows;
            mr.castShadows = origobj.renderer.castShadows;

            obj.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
            MeshFilter mer = obj.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
            mer.mesh = origobj.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;

            obj.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
            Rigidbody origrb = origobj.rigidbody;
            Rigidbody rb = obj.rigidbody;
            rb.isKinematic = origrb.isKinematic;
            rb.useGravity = origrb.useGravity;

            MeshCollider origmc = origobj.GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
            if (origmc) {
                MeshCollider mc = obj.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
                mc.sharedMesh = origmc.sharedMesh;
                mc.sharedMaterial = origmc.sharedMaterial;
            }
            BoxCollider origbc = origobj.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
            if (origbc) {
                BoxCollider bc = obj.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
                bc.sharedMaterial = origbc.sharedMaterial;
            }

            obj.transform.parent = terr.transform;
            obj.transform.localPosition = origobj.transform.localPosition;
            obj.transform.localRotation = origobj.transform.localRotation;
            obj.transform.localScale = origobj.transform.localScale;

            obj.SetActive(true);
        }
        return terr;
```

Comment: How many `GameObject` instances do you have?

Comment: In an ideal case I would have 1 GameObject per tile (in memory). I have a buffer atm, but it is irrelevant for the case described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, there is no way to circumvent the spikes caused from MeshColliders. They are extremely costly, it is better to use a generic one or write your own collider.

Additionally, what you are doing is going to be cost excessive amounts of resources regardless. The best way to handle it all is use a single mesh for all your tiles and render GameObjects only when physics is invoked or you could write your own physics.

Another option is to create a "chunk" mechanic to group tiles together. Then you can create some type of culling, loading and unloading chunks to improve performance.

In short, it's highly unlikely you'll be able to do this in a cost effective with just Unity's core libraries.

Comment: What I do now is loading the colliders when they are in a short range of the player. I have some meshcombining for the small tiles (in chunks), but it doesn't seem affective for large meshes somehow, slowing the game down significantly.

Comment: I'd say play more with different chunk sizes and the amount of colliders you're loading/unloading at any given time. Also consider building a queue for the whole process.